# Karate: How to use a datatable in a java function?

Tags: java, cucumber, karate

I have a feature file that looks like:

```
* def javaFunction = Java.type('my.javaClass');
* def generateFile = new javaFunction().functionName(???)
```

And my function looks like

```
public String functionName(DataTable dm){
  for (DataModel aDataModel : dm) {
      String username = aDataModel.user;
      String password = aDataModel.password;
  }
}
```

I want to use a Data table that looks like this but I'm not sure how to call it in the functionName(???) in my .feature file

```
|user       |password |
|cucumber1  |cucumber |
|cucumber2  |cucumber |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are expecting Karate to work like Cucumber, no that's not how it works. There's no such thing as a `DataTable` in Karate.

Please spend some time how Karate uses JSON arrays where you want to loop over a data source: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#data-driven-features

And there is a way to do dynamic scenario outlines, look it up: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#setup

Comment: Is there a way to itirate through the JsList with Java? - This is the error I am getting when calling the table in my Java fucntion org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (updateJson) on helpers.JSonUtils@202f054f failed due to: Cannot convert '[{key=abc, value=abc}]'(language: Java, type: com.intuit.karate.graal.JsList) to Java type 'com.intuit.karate.graal.JsList': Unsupported target type.

Comment: Found my answer - In Java I need to call for a Java List - I can then iterate through it